How to disable keyboard input from displaying on the terminal while still detecting keypress events in Node.js?
I am new to NodeJS. I am working on a Node.js application where I need to disable keyboard input from being displayed on the terminal screen. However, I still want to detect keypress events. I want to allow the user to press keys (like spacebar) without those keys being printed on the screen, but I need to capture the keypress events for other functionalities.
I have a function spell that writes text character by character to the terminal, which can skip to the end when the spacebar is pressed and needs the spacebar to be pressed again to end.
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});
KHGO={};
process.stdin.on('keypress', (str, key) => {
  KHGO[key.name] = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    KHGO[key.name] = false;
  }, 100);
});

async function spell(string, ms){
  let skipped = false;
  const characterArray = string.split("");
    console.log("");
  //Write character by character if space is pressed write everything
  for (let i = 0; i < characterArray.length; i++) {
    process.stdout.write(string[i]);
    if (!skipped) await sleep(ms);
    if (KHGO.space) skipped = true;
    KHGO.space = false;
  }
  //wait until space is pressed to continue
  while(true){
    if(KHGO.space){
      KHGO.space=false;
      return;
    }
    await sleep(1);
  }
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

(async function(){
  await spell("Example text",40);
  await spell("Example text2",40);
})();

But when you skip, the space is seen in the text, plus any other keys you press are also visible. I also don't want to permanently disable keyboard writing, I want some kind of functions like disableKeyboard() and enableKeyboard()

Please post your "full code": https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example complete the tour and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

You dont use any rl.write, and  write directly to stdout, remove output: process.stdout from the createInterface option.

Removing output: process.stdout from the createInterface options causes the program to stop detecting keypresses.

Edit
It does work for me when using the "keypress" module (in a Linux terminal).
const keypress = require('keypress')
keypress(process.stdin)
process.stdin.setRawMode(true)
process.stdin.resume()

let space = false
process.stdin.on('keypress', (str, key) => {
  if (key.name === 'space') {
    space = true
  }
})

async function spell (string, ms = 40) {
  const characters = string.split('')
  process.stdout.write('\n')
  for (let i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
    process.stdout.write(characters[i])
    if (!space) await sleep(ms)
  }
  space = false
  while (!space) {
    await sleep(100)
  }
  space = false
}

function sleep (ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

(async function () {
  await spell('Example text 1')
  await spell('Example text 2')
  // to be able to do Ctrl+C again
  process.stdin.setRawMode(false)
  // or exit the process right away
  process.stdin.pause()
})()



I am assuming you are using npm i keypress which you don't mention. To diable the echo of the keys pressed, you can switch to raw mode:
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);

Which you can switch back at any time. And you also need to tell stdin to resume so your process does not immediately exit.
process.stdin.resume();


I am using the readline module, not keypress. I tried switching to raw mode, but the keys are still being displayed on the screen. Additionally, I now have to press Enter after space to finish or skip.
